# kernel/linux/igb_uio/meson.build:6:17: ERROR: lexer

Tags: linux, build, dpdk, meson-build

I am trying to build igb_uio kernel module using meson build. I am using the following meson.build file to build the driver.

**file: kernel/linux/igb_gio/meson.build**

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
# Copyright(c) 2017 Intel Corporation

mkfile = custom_target('igb_uio_makefile',
    output: 'Makefile',
    command: ['touch', '@OUTPUT@'])

custom_target('igb_uio',
    input: ['igb_uio.c', 'Kbuild'],
    output: 'igb_uio.ko',
    command: ['make', '-C', kernel_dir,
        'M=' + meson.current_build_dir(),
        'src=' + meson.current_source_dir(),
        'EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I' + meson.current_source_dir() +
            '/../../../lib/librte_eal/common/include',
        'modules'],
    depends: mkfile,
    install: true,
    install_dir: kernel_dir + '/../extra/dpdk',
    build_by_default: get_option('enable_kmods'))
```

MY build is failing with error : kernel/linux/igb_uio/meson.build:6:17: ERROR:  lexer
command: [touch, @OUTPUT@])

I have tried passing file name as
igb_src = files(igb_uio.c', 'Kbuild'), then assigning input: igb_src but no luck. Can you please tell me how to fix this issue? I am using meson version .49.2

Comment: please update the ticket with the necessary information, `kernel version, where to download the file, any custom changes, and steps to reproduce the error`. Since these are not found marking the question as need more informatiom.

Comment: hope you had a chance to look into the environment path for touch from the meson environment. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon DPDK versions IGB_UIO Kernel driver code can be present or absent in DPDK source. Upto dpdk version 19.11 LTS, it is part of source folder. From DPDK version 20.02 and higher onwards, the files are removed and need to be built separately. ***But in both cases this is self contained built environment, without the need for external intervention.***

The current error `kernel/linux/igb_uio/meson.build:6:17: ERROR: lexer command: [touch, @OUTPUT@])` is not part of DPDK build (makefile or meson) issue but rather the lexer is not able to find `touch`. This seems more of environment and setup issue.

On generic Linux OS distros (fedora, debian, rhel, centos or ubuntu) `touch` is normally found in `/usr/bin/`. In case of custom kernel or docker environment, ensure to share or update PATH to reflect `touch`. Then execute as below

For DPDK 20.02 and higher:

```
git clone http://dpdk.org/git/dpdk-kmods
dpdk-kmods/linux/igb_uio/
make
modprobe uio
insmod igb_uio.ko
```

***Note: irrespective of DPDK version, one can use this method for kernel module***

For DPDK version 19.11 LTS and lower:

meson build:

1. ensure in file `meson_options.txt` the value for `enable_kmods` is `TRUE`.
2. execute `meson custombuild; ninja -C custombuild install; cd custombuild/kmod/`
3. use `modprobe uio; insmod igb_uio.ko`

Makefile build:

1. build config folder using `make config T=[desired target] O=[output folder]`
2. edit `[output folder]/.config` to ensure `CONFIG_RTE_EAL_IGB_UIO` is set `y`
3. set RTE_SDK and RTE_TARGET, and execute `make -j`
4. use `modprobe uio; insmod igb_uio.ko`